# Toggle between two different vim configurations?

Tags: vim

I've got a .vimrc and .vim folder I've been tweaking for a while, but on my machine at a new job, I've just installed [ryanb's dotfiles](https://github.com/ryanb/dotfiles) (which contains config files for vim, git, and more). There are things I like in each config, so ultimately I want to combine them into a new personal config. Meanwhile, I'd like to be able to switch back and forth.

Is there an easy command for this in vim - "use the following .vimrc and .vim directory" - or would it be more straightforward to swap out the files themselves when I want to switch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `-u` option will allow you to specify a configuration file other than ~/.vimrc, but there is no option to specify an alternative to the ~/.vim directory. However, you can have Vim use a different directory by modifying the 'runtimepath' ('rtp') option in each of your configuration files. For example, you could use this command

```
let &rtp = substitute(&rtp, '\.vim\>', '.vim1', 'g')
```

in one of your configuration files to tell Vim to use the ~/.vim1 directory rather than the ~/.vim directory.

Comment: I'm guessing I can use this to keep everything in Dropbox :)

Comment: @Michael Caron - you can keep your `.vimrc` and `.vim` anywhere you like, as long as you have symlinks in your home folder to wherever you put them. Personally, I use this trick to keep all my configs in a `.dotfiles` folder, which I can sync to Github.

Answer (score 4):

`-u` tells vim to use an alternate vimrc file.

Comment: I recently learned that `vim -u "NONE"` opens vanilla vim, with no configuration. That can be useful if you've got a complex configuration and want to know whether some behavior is native to Vim or not. (This also works for MacVim - I haven't tried Gvim on Linux.)

Answer (score 2):

### Toggle Config by Replacing Directory Symlink

I have following setup:

```
❯ tree -L  2 ~/.vim-configs
~/.vim-configs
├── nathanl
│   ├── .git
│   ├── gvimrc
│   ├── pack
│   └── vimrc
├── ryanb
│   ├── autoload
│   ├── ...
│   └── vimrc
└── minimal
    ├── autoload
    ├── cache
    ├── doc
    ├── plugin
    └── vimrc

❯ ls -l ~/.vim
lrwxr-xr-x  1 hotschke  staff  42 Apr  3 16:35 .vim -> /Users/hotschke/.vim-configs/minimal
```

If you want to change to a different config, you simply have to execute

```
❯ ln -snf ~/.vim-configs/configX ~/.vim
```

#### Optional: shell function with tab complete for switching config

If you are ambitious, you could write a minimal shell function with autocompletion to make this superconvenient. For example if you use zsh, you 
could use

```zsh
# Swim - Switch Vim Configs
compdef '_path_files -/ -W ~/.vim-configs' swim
function swim {
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
    zmodload zsh/stat
    active=$(stat +link "$HOME/.vim")
    echo "Swimming with ${${active}:t}"
    echo "$HOME/.vim -> $active"
    zmodload -u zsh/stat
  else
    echo "Swimming with $1"
    ln -snfv ~/.vim-configs/$1 ~/.vim
  fi
}
```

It already provides tab completion and works everywhere in your file system:

```
❯ pwd
<somewhere in your filesystem not necessarily $HOME or $HOME/.vim>
❯ swim <Tab>
-- directory --
minimal/  nathanl/  ryanb/
❯ swim minimal
Swimming with minimal
/Users/hotschke/.vim -> /Users/hotschke/.vim-configs/minimal
❯ swim
Swimming with minimal
/Users/hotschke/.vim -> /Users/hotschke/.vim-configs/minimal
```

(function name stolen from https://github.com/dawsbot/swim)

Comment: Good solution, I suggest to add a alias for each config like `alias vimbasic="ln -snf ~/.vim-configs/basic/ ~/.vim && vim"`, so you can change your config just typing the alias like `vimbasic`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Vim Plugin Manager *Volt*

https://github.com/vim-volt/volt

Installation on macOS: `$ brew install volt`

> The feature “profile” saves a set of plugins, vimrc, and gvimrc.
>
> You can switch combinations with one command. For example, you can switch
>   from a web development setup to essential plugins + vimrc, or vanilla vim.

This is also helpful creating minimal configurations when raising questions on stackexchange network or issues on github for vim/vim plugins.